# hive sql sorted query compare last value

Tags: sql, hive

I have a records that have been sorted by id and number in my query. I have to build a logic where it checks the row above it and if it fits a certain criteria it gets assigned the same value as another column. The logic is as follows

```
if [row-1:id] != [id] and is null ([first_time])
then [my_date]
else [first_time]
endif
```

in my query i have

```
select
 case when
   lag(my_date) over (partition by id  order by id ASC, first_time ASC) and  
   first_time is Null then my_date
   else first_time
   end
   from
   mytable
```

The query i have written above will not compile. is this the right query logic to handle the expression i listed above?

Comment: give us sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You have `lag()`, but no comparison.  You would seem to want something like:

```
select (case when first_time is null
                  lag(id, 1, -1) over (order by ?) <> id
             then my_date else first_time
        end)
from my_table;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering in the table -- the definition of "the row above"